# Difference between zones and locations endpoints in GKE clusters API

Tags: google-api, google-kubernetes-engine

When I began working with the GKE API, I was surprised to find two very similar endpoints:

- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters
- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters

A quick look at the difference between them reveals that some methods and fields are rearranged, some are deprecated, but no documentation that explains the difference between these two.

I initially thought that the first is for creating zonal, and that latter for creating regional clusters, yet when creating a cluster via Google Cloud Console there's an "Equivalent REST" option, which shows that both cases use the same `projects.zones.clusters` endpoint.

So, what's the difference between these endpoints, and in which scenarios one would use `projects.locations.clusters`?

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent REST option in Google Cloud Console now uses different endpoints for the two cluster types:

- Regional: `projects.locations.clusters`
- Zonal: `projects.zones.clusters`